# Google Sheets : horizontal (row) conditional Arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have row 1 containing some dates (undetermined number, because end formula will be a dynamic number) and I want row 5 to display the average of every column that has a date as a header.

Trying to have this array formula work :

```
arrayformula(iferror(
if(B1:1 = "",,
AVERAGE(
indirect(
SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(B1:1),4),"1","") 
& 7 & ":" & 
SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(B1:1),4),"1","")
)))))
```

I think I did isolate the problem in the arrayformula, I can't see where the problem lies with it ?

Here's a screenshot :
[image]

and here's the link to the spreadsheet :

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GbIWwv0lq6nVdn4dHkSO0-QqZYEPCwJtntCu8wcSd9Q/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `QUERY` method:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B1:1="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(COLUMN(B1:1),QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B7:7)&"♦"&B7:1000)),"♦"),"select Col1,avg(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label avg(Col2) ''",0),2,FALSE),)))
```

#### `MMULT` method:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B1:1="",,IFERROR(MMULT(N(TRANSPOSE(ROW(B7:1000)^0)),N(B7:1000))/MMULT(N(TRANSPOSE(ROW(B7:1000)^0)),N(B7:1000<>"")),)))
```

Comment: ty it works ...
but ...
It's painfully slow, especially for a simplified test page : I did several tests and it takes about 7 seconds to update.
I'm afraid it might get too slow on the production file.
I will make some more tests.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: it takes about 10 seconds to update the production sheet.
I hope someone comes with a faster solution.
Do you think my approach is wrong and cannot be used with somewhat slight corrections / modifications ?
I will either use it if the delay is acceptable for the users, or if no one has a better solution, make it a script.

Comment: Added another method, please check.

Comment: ty : I will need to understand what you're doing here :-)

It works well, but it doesn't work into the production sheet, so I tried to duplicate the test sheet (same data exactly in the same reference cells) and the exact same formula, but also get a blank result, with no error message. 
I'm puzzled ...

Comment: Edit : a pure duplicate of the sheet produces the expected result, but rebuilding another sheet with the same data and same formula in the same cells doesn't work.

Comment: OK : it works alright; I guess I introduced some error somewhere.
Best of all it is now fast on the production sheet :-)
Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: funnily, Youtube "suggests" a 5-month old video on MMULT
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OLyQYioCDmU
Maybe I will understand the formula now :-P
Thank you algo !